# Rails group_by custom method (Levenshtein distance)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I have these ActiveRecords

```
items = [{title: "Title 1"}, {title: "Title 2"}, {title: "Title 3"}]
```

Now I want to group items that have similar title (using function Levenshtein distance > 70%).

I was thinking something like `item.group_by{}` but I wonder how to calculate score for each combination? I have to compare *title1* with *title3* and *title2* with *title3* etc..

```
def levenshtein_distance(title_a, title_b)
    ... 
    return score
end
```

I tried using a clustering algorithm (KMedoids with non-euclidian metric) but I don't know the cluster size (k) a-priori.

Comment: `group_by` only works for absolute metrics. What you want is [clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis).

Comment: @Stefan I tried with Kmedoids but I don't the cluster size (k) a-priori.

Comment: You could use the Fuzzy Match gem https://github.com/seamusabshere/fuzzy_match

Comment: This is not necessarily a database agnostic question. For example, Postgres has an explicit `LEVENSHTEIN` method, so a solution for Postgres would be different than one for SQLite or MySQL. What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this.

```
matrix = {}
items.each_with_index do |item_a, i|
  matrix["#{items[i].id}"] = []
  items.each_with_index do |item_b, j|
    if String::Similarity.cosine(item_a.title, item_b.title) > 0.9
      matrix["#{items[i].id}"] << items[j] 
    end
  end
end

puts matrix.inspect

 matrix.each do |key, items|
  ....
 end
```